# pandas dataframe xlsxwriter write to excel : treat zero as blank

Tags: pandas, dataframe, zero

I am writing several dataframes to a excel file in different sheet.
I need treat  0 only value as blank, but not 0.006, 10.02%  which contain 0 as blank.  Like this

```
      0       blank     
      0.02    0.02        not affected
      10.02%  10.02%      not affected
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace zeros with `np.nan` then write to excel.  `to_excel` by default, treats `np.nan` as `''`

```
df.mask(df.eq(0)).to_excel()
```